# Spring boot @restcontroller upload error

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, retrofit2, okhttp

I am new to spring boot and android development. I'm trying to set up and android app (using retrofit and okhttp3) which will upload images to my server.

Server code:

```
@RestController
public class ImageController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadImage", method =RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public String greeting(@RequestPart(value="desc") RequestBody desc, @RequestPart(value="img") MultipartBody.Part image) {
        System.out.println("Works");
        return "Works";
    }
}
```

Android code:

```
MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", imageFile.getName(), requestBody);
RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), imageFile.getName());


@Multipart
@POST("/uploadImage")
Observable<retrofit2.Response<String>> uploadPhoto(@Part("desc") RequestBody desc,@Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

Error:

> {"timestamp":1519756785858,"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Content type 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' not supported","path":"/uploadImage"}

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong????

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Next time please format your code properly,
so that it is better readable for others. This time I did it for you.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Try this...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String greeting(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

        //to save file, if it is your case
        Path path = Paths.get("/" + file.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(path, bytes);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I didn't understand very well your Android code, but I'd try something like this:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://url");

httpPost.setEntity(new FileEntity(new File("filePath"), "application/octet-stream"));

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: but then i get the error 

{"timestamp":1519844515434,"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=ad983eba-75d8-49cd-bbdc-e48f1ef44814' not supported","path":"/uploadImage"}

Comment: @bdeane I have editted the answer. Check if it will help you.